# Converting Nav to Dropdown from css-tricks.com

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to convert my five-item navigation menu (with internal links on the same page) to a dropdown menu at a certain width.
I've followed the directions from [here](http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/) exactly but the creator doesn't mention how to include internal links in the dropdown. I'm obviously missing something, but does anybody know how to include a simple internal link (e.g. #, #aboutme, #contact) within the

```
<select>
```

element?

Thanks

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqp65/) - it's almost exactly the same as the link above

Comment: Please include your current CSS and HTML markup

Comment: ok @DrydenLong I added a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Look well at the link you provide:

> Then to make the dropdown menu actually work...

```
$("nav select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

So in your markup it looks like:

```
<option value="#books">Books</option>
```

Where value is the reference to go.

Comment: That's what I tried to do but the menu item doesn't actually go to the anchor on the site. Am I missing something? I just added a fiddle onto my question so you can have a look at my code

Comment: works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/Sqp65/6/ try with about and contact options

Comment: Its really bizarre. Instead of a div I'm using an a, but my code looks just like yours. 
My nav ul works fine on the site but once the browser is resized and the dropdown appears, the links dont go anywhere... What else could be causing this?

Comment: I just can't see your problem try to replicate all your code including a tags and CSS in the fiddle